# What is a peer class in Java?

Tags: java, oop, class, terminology

I came across the fact `StringBuffer` is called peer class of `String`. What is a peer class?

Comment: Came across this exact phrase on Page. 369 of Java 2: The Complete Reference by Herbert Schildt, Ed. 5., in case anybody cares :)

Answer (score 15):

First of all: You have to be careful with the term "peer class", because in Java it has a distinct meaning: Peer classes are "interfaces" to native classes. (a C++ class for example) (See the other anwsers for details)

In your case the term seems **not** to be used in that specific context!

Whoever called `StringBuffer` a peer class to `String` obviously used that word in a *general* sense. In a way `StringBuffer` and `String` are related and both of them can be used for similar purposes. I guess in some use cases they could be considered peers in the broader sense of the word.

Answer (score 5):

As I know, peer classes are written to connect the code with the native code.
See this article, http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-peer-class/.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers