# What does JavaFrame do in Matlab?

Tags: java, matlab, undocumented-behavior

I see that code

```
plot(1:5); 
jFrame = get(gcf,'JavaFrame');
```

it works and returns some result.

What does it return? What is background of this functional? Is it documented? I can't find `JavaFrame` property in the list of figure properties. How can I find more similar functions?

Comment: follow this http://eddiema.ca/2011/07/11/exposing-matlab-data-with-jframe-jtextarea/

Comment: note the warning: http://www.mathworks.com/javaframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a hidden property of the figure handle, and it's undocumented. According to [Yair Altman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233829/yair-altman)'s blog ["Undocumented Matlab"](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/displaying-hidden-handle-properties/), it enables access to the GUI’s underlying [Java peer object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562164/what-is-a-peer-class-in-java).

Answer (score 3):

It's an undocumented hidden property of the figure that returns a handle to the underlying `JFrame` of the MATLAB figure window, which is implemented in Java. There are lots of things that you can do with it - to find out about them, read some of the articles on Yair Altman's [blog](http://undocumentedmatlab.com) "Undocumented MATLAB".